# How do I check if a string is contained within a list in batch

Tags: batch-file

I try and avoid using batch if at all possible, as I don't like the syntax, or the lack of an inbuilt IDE, so I am pretty much a beginner with it. What I am trying to do is write an installation program, mainly in python but this part has to be done in batch, and i have written all the installation instructions, but i am now stuck on checking a user's input. What I want it to do is to get a users input (done) and then tell if it is `yes`, `Yes`, `y` or `Y` and if so, then install that part of the program. I have decided to try and use lists because that seems the simplest way, but i honestly have never used them before in batch, and so have no idea how they work. So basically I want to check if a variable exists within a list.

I know this has probably been asked before, but i couldn't find an answer that satisfied my question (admittedly i could have looked harder, but I'm tired).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
choice /c YN
If errorlevel 2 echo No Selected
If errorlevel 1 echo Yes Selected
```

I don't like people who post they don't like batch then ask a question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it has worked perfectly for me. Sorry that I've annoyed you, but I was, as were probably most of the others, mainly posting the fact that I/we don't like batch as an excuse for being so bad at it.

Comment: The history of batch is a simple, step by step, language that automated or mirrored what you typed to operate the computer. IBM engineers for OS/2 retrofitted programming concepts in batchfile. Using it as it was designed it is a simple and easy to understand language (exactly the same as what you typed anyway). With IBM's and later MS improvments it a dogs dinner. Worse, it's undesigned behaviour are treated like features by some making it three things in one.

Comment: I understand that batch was designed to be easy to use, but it has different syntax to other programming languages (e.g: python and javascript) and I, personally, prefer to use these as I have been using them the longest, and so am used to their syntax.

Comment: Batch is good for copying or deleting files and starting programs. Anything else a language (which batch isn't) is best.

Answer (score 1):

Although `choice` (as suggested in [Noodles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35951480)) is probably the best way for such user input queries, I still want to show you another method (using built-in commands only):

```
set /P QUERY="Say yes or no: "
if /I not "%QUERY%"=="y" if /I not "%QUERY%"=="yes" goto :NO
:YES
echo You said "yes".
goto :SKIP
:NO
echo You said "no" or something else.
:SKIP
rem Continue script here...
```

The `set /P` command prompts you for input. The concatenated `if` commands constitute a kind of logical *AND*; together with the `not` keyworks, the condition is fulfilled if you typed anything else than `y` or `yes`; the `/I` switch makes the comparison case-insensitive.

Instead of the `echo`-s you can put any command(s) of course, or you `goto` somewhere else in the code.

Notice that the command extensions need to be enabled (as per Windows' default) for this to work (type `set /?` and also `cmd /?` in a command prompt window for details).